# Modify code so scrolling also triggers it

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to modify the below code so that not only a click outside the menu, but also scrolling down, will trigger closing the menu?

```
var closeDelay = 50;
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#main-content, .et-l--footer, .et_menu_container a').each(function() {
                $(this).click(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                                           if ($('.et_mobile_menu').is(':visible')) {
                            $('.mobile_menu_bar_toggle').trigger('click');}
                    }, closeDelay);
                });
            });
        }, 1200);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

It's currently live @ semita.pl.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: you can use jQuery scroll event, like `$(window).scroll( function() { /* if menu is visible then trigger click here */ })`

Comment: but for this to work correctly, you should rely on a different condition than `:visible`, since there is a transition present, this is more precise: `if ($('.mobile_nav').hasClass('opened'))`

Comment: result: https://i.ibb.co/jVgS3j9/Peek-30-05-2022-18-35.gif